# jQuery .show() not working on <span> tag

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

This seems like it would be pretty straightforward. I have a text box and I want a link to display based on whether or not there is content in there. In my `document.ready` I have the code set to

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#searchValue').change(function () {
            if ($('#searchValue').val().length > 0) {
                $('#home').show();
            } else {
                $('#home').hide();
            }
    });
```

and here is the section from my ASP MVC view with the links I'm referring to. I want everything outside the span to display when the page loads, everytime. Anything in the `span`, only when there is information in the text box.

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") |
    @Html.ActionLink("Export to Spreadsheet", "ExportToCsv") 
    <span class="home" style="display:none;">
    | @Html.ActionLink("Back to Index", "Index")       
    </span>
```

I've tried this with and without the `style="display:none;"` attribute and I cannot get the `.show()` or `.hide()` to  fire. I have stepped through the code and can see that the condition in the `doucment.ready` is working, however, and that part of the code is being reached.

Comment: the span contains the class attribute home not the ID. If you change it to <span id="home" /> then your code will work, Or otherwise change your jQuery code from $("#home") to $(".home")

Comment: Use `if (!!$(this).val())` instead of `if ($('#searchValue').val().length > 0)` to simplify that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need class selector instead of [`id selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), You have home as class of span not the id  either you assign home to id or use [`class selector`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

*Change*

```
 $('#home')
```

*To*

```
$('.home')
```

*You code would be*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchValue').change(function () {
        if ($('#searchValue').val().length > 0) {
            $('.home').show();
        } else {
            $('.home').hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: a situation that might be happening to others is the use of the style 'visibility' rather than 'display', which was my case.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling span id of home and it actually is the class.

Change to `$('.home')`

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough:

```
$('#searchValue').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) $('.home').show();
    else $('.home').hide();
});
```